# Selenium Google searching in loop

Tags: search, selenium, phrase

I have to create a test script in Selenium which found and click correct link in google search engine.
Script should open google website later enter searched phrase (for example: "ipod blog") later should in results on current page search correct item (for this example: "iPadOS: iOS Blog") when it wouldn't be presented on this page should automatically press "Next page button" and go to next page to moment when correct item will be found (in my case that item is on 21st page of results in google). When element will be found script should stored in log number of page where this item was found.
Can anybody help with this or give any useful tips.
I know how to create this script step by step but I haven't any idea how to create loop for searching correct phrase on google pages and later executed next.

Comment: can you show what uve tried so far?

Comment: to be honest with I didn't have to much because my previous automation tests based on repetitive steps according to test scripts. I have flow chart how it should look and basic scripts which open Google website, enter searched phrase and execute search button. I have also function verify text which try find searched name. I'm stuck in place where I should put loop options which makes repetition with text verify and next button.

Comment: Well what programming language are you using? You aren't looking for anything special, just a standard `while` loop in your language. That's all.

Comment: Arran your advice was good enough. Thanks